# Trouble moving QGraphicsItemGroup with grid snapping

Tags: python, qgraphicsscene, pyqt6, qgraphicsitemgroup

I am having trouble moving a subclass of QGraphicsItemGroup around a QGraphicsScene with the mouse. The scene has a grid that I want the group to snap to as it moves. To accomplish this I have reimplemented the itemChange function in my subclass as follows:

```
from os import environ

environ["QT_ENABLE_HIGHDPI_SCALING"] = "0"

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *

app = QApplication([])

class GridSnappingQGIG(QGraphicsItemGroup):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
        
    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.childrenBoundingRect()
        
    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        scene = self.scene()
        if change == QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemChange.ItemPositionChange and scene:
            scene = self.scene()
            x, y = scene.snap_to_grid(value.x(), value.y(), scene.grid_size)
            bounding_rect = self.boundingRect()
            x, y = min(8192 - bounding_rect.width(), max(0, x)), min(8192 - bounding_rect.height(), max(0, y))
            return QPointF(x, y)
        return super().itemChange(change, value)

class Scene(QGraphicsScene):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.grid_size = 32
        
    def snap_to_grid(self, x, y, grid_size):
        return [grid_size * round(x / grid_size), grid_size * round(y / grid_size)]
scene = Scene(0, 0, 8192, 8192)

rect1 = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 32, 32)
scene.addItem(rect1)
rect1.setPos(4000,4000)

rect2 = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 128, 256)
scene.addItem(rect2)
rect2.setPos(3680,3680)

group = GridSnappingQGIG()
scene.addItem(group)
group.addToGroup(rect1)
group.addToGroup(rect2)

view = QGraphicsView(scene)
view.showMaximized()    
app.exec()
```

snap_to_grid is a function in my scene class which finds the nearest point on a scene.grid_size x scene.grid_size grid to the input point (x, y). The entire scene is 8192x8192 pixels, so the min/max operations ensure the item is not moved outside the scene.

After calling scene.addToItem(ItemGroup), I can move the group, but only right or down, not up or left. This is the behavior I would expect if the boundingRectangle's top-left corner was (0, 0) (in scene coordinates). I implemented the virtual boundingRect() function to return the childrenBoundingRect(), but this didn't fix the problem. I figured maybe I needed to adjust the position after adding the group to the scene. I tried getting the top-left corner (x, y) of the group in scene coordinates by calling mapToScene on the top-left corner of the bounding rectangle and then calling setPos(x, y), but then the group got pushed in the down-right direction as soon as I tried to move it.

I have tried commenting out the itemChange function, in which case the movement behaves as expected (but without the grid-snapping, of course). The grid snapping implementation also behaves as expected for custom QGraphicsItems subclasses.

Some system information:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Home
OS Version:                10.0.19045 N/A Build 19045

Python 3.10.2

PyQt6                        6.4.2
pyqt6-plugins                6.4.2.2.3
PyQt6-Qt6                    6.4.3
PyQt6-sip                    13.5.2
pyqt6-tools                  6.4.2.3.3

qt6-applications             6.4.3.2.3
qt6-tools                    6.4.3.1.3
```

Comment: This shouldn't happen, theoretically. Unless you did something else in `itemChange` for the items that become part of the group, or the snap function isn't reliable. Your `boundingRect()` override is correct, as QGraphicsItemGroup is very elementary (it only updates its bounding rect when items are added or removed, but it doesn't consider item changes that could happen in the meantime); still, this should consider the relative position of items, unless there are some other aspects in play. I strongly suggest you to provide a valid and complete [mre].

Comment: @musicamante I added a complete MRE.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this on Linux with both Qt5 and Qt6 (6.3.1). I don't use a High DPI system, and that **may** be an important aspect (and, therefore, a possible bug). Please [edit] your post with *detailed* info about your environment (including versions of your OS, Python, PyQt and Qt) and possible env/os/system configurations.

Comment: @musicamante I edited my post. I'm pretty sure I only have the subset of Qt automatically installed by pip. I tried enabling the high DPI scaling, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I appear to have discovered the problem. The coordinates value.x() and value.y() are not the old scene coordinates of the item group, but rather the displacement in the x and y directions, respectively, from the group's original position. This means that if you try to move the group leftward or upward, value.x() and value.(y) are always negative. Then max(x, 0) = max(y, 0) = 0, and so (0, 0) is returned, resulting in no movement.

Comment: No, the `value` of `itemChange` for position changes is always relative to the parent (which may be the scene), not the "displacement" (the *delta*). You're missing the point, though: the group is added to the scene, and you're actually snapping its position related to the scene, not that of its items. Note that I *am* able to reproduce your problem, but only because now I understand that your explanation was ambiguous: your phrase "I can move the group, but only right or down" means that it is *always impossible* to move items up/left, even after they've been moved down/right. »

Comment: » In reality, what you probably meant is that you are not able to move items *above* or *beyond the left* of their current, initial position, which is a very different thing. Your problem is that you want to be able to snap items that have a *relative* position that can potentially move the group beyond the top/left of the scene, because their geometries would still be within the scene rect. This means that you have to compute the position of the children bounding rect to the changed position, and then check whether or not they could still be within the allowed area.

Comment: I see how my initial statement was confusing. Sorry for that. Indeed, the problem was that I could not move the group above or to the left of the top-left corner of the group at the time it was placed on the scene. Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry, it happens. I'm writing an answer that addresses the issue also explaining the misunderstandings (yours and mine ;-) ).

Comment: I still don't understand why the item group behaves differently than individual items, since the item group has no parent.

Comment: It doesn't behave differently, but consistently. The problem is that you probably misunderstood the hierarchy of items and their relative geometries. 1. when items are added to a group, they are reparented to that group, while preserving their original position;; 2. the "parent" of any item can also be the scene itself, meaning that you have to consider the relative position of reparented items based on the group position within the scene. When an item is added to a new group (that is added to a scene) its position is identical to its original one, but, in reality, it's relative to the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Note: the original question was misguiding, leading to believe that *any* down/right movement was impossible; in reality, the problem was about not being able to move items *beyond* the top/left of their *initial* position.</sup>

The problem is mainly caused by a common misconception about QGraphicsItems: the *position* of an item doesn't always match that of their *contents*. As the QGraphicsScene documentation often reiterates, items position is *always* initialized to `(0, 0)`, which is relative to their parent (which may be the scene if no parent is set).

For example, `scene.addRect(50, 50, 100, 100)` will create a 100x100 square *shown* at `(50, 50)`, but the QGraphicsRectItem *position* will still be `(0, 0)`.

Consider the following:

```py
rect1 = scene.addRect(50, 50, 100, 100)
rect2 = scene.addRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
rect2.setPos(50, 50)
```

The above will result in two *visually* identical squares. Their positions do not match, though.

The same happens for QGraphicsItemGroup.

When you create a group, its original position will be the above mentioned `(0, 0)`, and its items will still be positioned at their original `pos()`. When items are added to a group, their position is virtually unchanged, preserving the original one based on their scene coordinates and related to the group's parent (yeah, I know, it's not that intuitive, but it makes sense as soon as you understand the relations between items).

This means that if you want to limit the items of that group within the scene area, you cannot use the group position as reference: you need to check whether the *translated* bounding rect would be within the scene limits, and eventually adjust the position based on the difference of the translation limited by the boundaries.

Unfortunately, this brings in a lot of other aspects caused by relative geometries: I *assumed* that your items **always** have geometries that respect the snap size, but if that is not the case, the implementation may become much more complex. The problem comes from the fact that you have to decide the reference geometry used for snapping: let's assume that the `grid_size` is 32, what should happen if an item is positioned at 15 (x or y) and its group is moved?

Then, there is another problem: the `boundingRect()` of items always is what the scene fundamentally uses for drawing purposes, which includes everything drawing needs: if you create a basic `(0, 0, 10, 10)` rectangle, its bounding rect will actually be `(-0.5, -0.5, 11, 11)`, because it includes the default pen width (see the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect)). But, in your case, you actually need to consider the actual geometry of the rectangle no matter the drawing geometry, so using the `boundingRect()` of the group (or its `childrenBoundingRect()`) would be inconsistent for that purpose.

As you can see, while not impossible, item geometry management may become quite complex unless you are aware of their behavior. All that shows the power and complexity of the graphics view framework.

Still, if you have a self-contained system in which you have complete control over the above aspects, there are relatively simple solutions.

In the following example, I'm using smaller scene and item sizes, with a function that considers both the scene "snap" and its boundaries.

```py
class GridSnappingQGIG(QGraphicsItemGroup):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.setFlags(
            QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable
            | QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemSendsGeometryChanges
        )

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        scene = self.scene()
        if (
            scene and
            change == QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemChange.ItemPositionChange
        ):
            # create the "real bounding rect" based on geometries of child
            # items, using their actual coordinates
            childrenRect = QRectF()
            for child in self.childItems():
                if isinstance(child, (QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsEllipseItem)):
                    childRect = child.rect()
                elif isinstance(child, QGraphicsPathItem):
                    childRect = child.path().boundingRect()
                elif isinstance(child, QGraphicsLineItem):
                    childRect = QRectF(child.line().p1(), child.line().p2())
                else:
                    # further implementation required for other item types, 
                    # in order to avoid issues based on pen widths, margins, 
                    # complex geometries, etc.
                    childRect = child.boundingRect()
                # adjust the children rect with the child position translated
                # to the *current* position (not the new one!)
                childrenRect |= childRect.translated(child.pos() + self.pos())

            # get the new possible geometry, based on the position difference
            adjustedRect = scene.adjusted_grid_rect(
                childrenRect.translated(value - self.pos()))
            diff = adjustedRect.topLeft() - childrenRect.topLeft()
            # return the difference between the computed moved rectangle and 
            # the current one, allowing proper "snapping"
            return self.pos() + diff

        return super().itemChange(change, value)

class Scene(QGraphicsScene):
    grid_size = 32
    def adjusted_grid_rect(self, rect):
        x = round(rect.x() / self.grid_size) * self.grid_size
        y = round(rect.y() / self.grid_size) * self.grid_size
        newRect = QRectF(x, y, rect.width(), rect.height())
        sceneRect = self.sceneRect()
        if newRect.right() > sceneRect.right():
            newRect.moveRight(sceneRect.right())
        if newRect.x() < sceneRect.x():
            newRect.moveLeft(sceneRect.x())
        if newRect.bottom() > sceneRect.bottom():
            newRect.moveBottom(sceneRect.bottom())
        if newRect.y() < sceneRect.y():
            newRect.moveTop(sceneRect.y())
        return newRect

    def drawBackground(self, qp, rect):
        # for testing purposes, draw the snap grid
        gs = self.grid_size
        sceneRect = self.sceneRect()
        qp.fillRect(rect & sceneRect, QColor(127, 127, 127, 63))
        qp.setPen(Qt.GlobalColor.lightGray)
        left, top, width, height = (rect & sceneRect).getRect()
        right = left + width
        bottom = top + height
        x = left // gs * gs
        if x == sceneRect.x():
            x += gs
        while x < right:
            qp.drawLine(QLineF(x, top, x, bottom))
            x += gs
        y = top // gs * gs
        if y == sceneRect.y():
            y += gs
        while y < bottom:
            qp.drawLine(QLineF(left, y, right, y))
            y += gs

app = QApplication([])

scene = Scene(0, 0, 640, 480)

rect1 = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 32, 32)
scene.addItem(rect1)
rect1.setPos(128, 128)

rect2 = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 64, 128)
scene.addItem(rect2)
rect2.setPos(256, 256)

group = GridSnappingQGIG()
scene.addItem(group)
group.addToGroup(rect1)
group.addToGroup(rect2)

view = QGraphicsView(scene)
view.setRenderHint(QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing)
view.resize(700, 700)
view.show()
QTimer.singleShot(10, lambda: 
    view.fitInView(scene.sceneRect(), Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio))
app.exec()
```

Note that the example doesn't consider the click-origin point, so its result may not be completely intuitive (the result changes depending on the origin point of the mouse press event). Consider this aspect along with the scene size and eventual scaling. For future reference, think about these aspects, as creating a scene that big may create issues both in debugging and UX.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed response. So the problem was that my item group's position was at (0, 0), yet I was using the position as a reference for snapping. Couldn't the initial problem then also be solved by creating a temporary group to find the actual top-left corner (x, y) of the childrenBoundingRect, then creating a new group and setting its position to (x, y) before adding the items?

Comment: That's a good idea, but it only partially solves the problem, as you still need to know the correct boundaries and you cannot use the bounding rect of the group for that due to the pen size aspect mentioned above. Note that you don't need to create a temporary group to get the actual coordinates: just iterate through the items that will be added and get their minimum x and y from the actual positions (again, considering the bounding rect and pen size).

Comment: In my actual program, the items in the group are custom classes whose boundaries are drawn with a width 0 pen, so I don't think the pen size should be an issue.

Comment: Then it's ok for that case. Just remember that you still need to translate the bounding rect to the position whenever the rect is not `(0, 0)` aligned (it's good practice to do it anyway, though). If the items are already in the scene and are not children of other items, you can also use `sceneBoundingRect()` to get the real origin point that you'll use for the group: `groupX = groupY = 8192` `for item in itemsToAdd:` `br = item.sceneBoundingRect()` `groupX = min(groupX, br.x())` `groupY = min(groupY, br.y())`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "translate the bounding rect" or the rect being "(0, 0) aligned".

Comment: @EthanAlwaise Remember the difference I explained above between items created to be shown at a certain position, or created at `0, 0` and then *moved* to that position. In your example your items are always `0, 0` aligned, but I don't know about the real code, for example if you allow resizing of items that alter the content geometries but not their item position.

Comment: I don't allow such changes in the real code. Both your solution and my proposed one seem to work in fine in the minimal example, and in the real code they **almost** work, yet sometimes (more often it seems if I move mouse violently), the group will jump all the way to the top-left of the screen. It also never happens on the first movement. When the mouse button is released, the group is destroyed and then when you try to move the items again, a new group is created, so that might have something to do with it.