# Grid snapping a QGraphicsItemGroup subclass

Tags: python, pyqt, qgraphicsitem

I am trying to make a custom subclass of QGraphicsItemGroup which snaps to a grid on a QGraphicsScene. I recently posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355901/trouble-moving-qgraphicsitemgroup-with-grid-snapping/77371543?noredirect=1#comment136411156_77371543) about this. My first problem was that I could not move the item groups to the left or right of their original position. I learned that I was forgetting that the initial position of an item is always `(0, 0)`, and so I was able to fix this by setting the position prior to adding items to the group. So the problem is solved for a single movement.

In my actual program, there are various objects on the scene and I want to be able to change which ones are being moved as a group. My approach is to create a new group when the mouse is pressed consisting of the objects I want to move, then destroy the group when the mouse is released. Here is a minimal working example:

```py
from os import environ

environ["QT_ENABLE_HIGHDPI_SCALING"] = "0"

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtGui import *

app = QApplication([])

class Location(QGraphicsItem):
    color = QColor(0, 110, 200, 75)
    border_color = QColor(0, 255, 0, 255)

    def __init__(self, size, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.width, self.height = size
        
    # def boundingRect(self):
    #     return QRectF(0, 0, 32*self.width, 32*self.height)

    def paint(self, *args):
        painter = args[0]
        painter.fillRect(1, 1, int(32*self.width) - 2, int(32*self.height) - 2, Location.color)
        
        pen = QPen(Location.border_color)
        pen.setWidth(0)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawRect(0, 0, int(32*self.width) - 1, int(32*self.height) - 1)
        
    def x(self):
        """Returns the x-coordinate of the location's position."""
        return int(self.pos().x())
    
    def y(self):
        """Returns the y-coordinate of the location's position."""
        return int(self.pos().y())
        

class GridSnappingQGIG(QGraphicsItemGroup):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemFlag.ItemSendsGeometryChanges, True)
        
    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.childrenBoundingRect()

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        scene = self.scene()
        if change == QGraphicsItem.GraphicsItemChange.ItemPositionChange and scene:
            x, y = scene.snap_to_grid(value.x(), value.y(), scene.grid_size)
            return QPointF(x, y)
        return super().itemChange(change, value)


class Scene(QGraphicsScene):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.grid_size = 32
        self.locations = []

    def snap_to_grid(self, x, y, grid_size):
        return [grid_size * round(x / grid_size), grid_size * round(y / grid_size)]
                
    def place_location(self, x, y, size):
        """Places a location of dimensions size at position (x, y)."""
        loc = Location(size)
        self.locations.append(loc)
        self.addItem(loc)
        loc.setPos(x, y)
                
    def move_locations(self, locations):
        """Puts the locations in the input list locations in a GridSnappingQGIG to move them."""
        x, y = min([loc.x() for loc in locations]), min([loc.y() for loc in locations])
        group = GridSnappingQGIG()
        self.addItem(group)
        group.setPos(x, y)
        
        for loc in locations:
            group.addToGroup(loc)
                
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.move_locations(self.locations)
        QGraphicsScene.mousePressEvent(self, event)
        
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        group = self.locations[0].group()
        for loc in self.locations:
            group.removeFromGroup(loc)
        self.removeItem(group)
        QGraphicsScene.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)

scene = Scene(0, 0, 480, 480)
scene.setBackgroundBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0))

scene.place_location(128, 128, [2,2])
scene.place_location(64, 64, [2,2])

frame = QFrame()
window = QMainWindow()
view = QGraphicsView(scene)

layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(view)
frame.setLayout(layout)

window.setCentralWidget(frame)
window.showMaximized()    
app.exec()
```

The problem is two-fold: Firstly, if you try to move the locations a second time, the newly created group jumps wildly past the mouse cursor. Secondly, the program is pretty prone to crashing with no error message. I suspect both problems are due to some mismanagement of memory (i.e. Python still holds a reference to some C++ object that has been deleted or vice versa), as I know that is a common cause of crashes in PyQt6 and I don't see how else the movement operation would behave differently a second time.

EDIT: Per the comments, getting rid of the `boundingRect` override in the `Scene` class solves the crashing problem, but not the jumpiness problem. I reduced the scene size from 8192x8192 to 480x480 and removed boundary checking.

Comment: Since it seems like you're not really interested in geometry changes of child items, overriding `boundingRect()` is unnecessary. Interestingly enough, based on my tests, removing that override solves the freeze/crash issue. I was not able to reproduce the first issue you mentioned.

Comment: That's odd. Getting rid of the```boundingRect()``` override seems to have solved both problems.

Comment: I just made a simple test with my default environment based on an old Qt5, but the graphics view framework hasn't changed that much in the meantime. I'm going to test it under Qt6 and will tell you if something changes. Note: as already suggested, it really helps *reducing* the context of the problem, not only for its code but also for the conceptual aspects it deals with: for instance, by using a smaller scene rect size; it may not "solve" the problem, but it will provide a more focused context; and if the result changes, then you also have a further reference to closely inspect the problem.

Comment: I just tested with PyQt6 (Qt 6.3.1) and removing the `boundingRect()` override doesn't show any issue, like Qt5. The problem may be related to memory management, but I'm not able to track down the possible source right now; as far as I know, QGraphicsItemGroup only updates its bounding rect with an internal computation of child items whenever they are added or removed, and there should be no memory leak about previous items. I can't test with PySide6, but I can reproduce it with PySide2 (Qt5) as with PyQt. This doesn't mean that it is a Qt problem, it may still be an issue with the binding.

Comment: Yeah I spoke a bit too soon as the problem still seems to be there. It seems to occur more frequently (or perhaps only) when the clicking is done while the mouse is moving. It's as if the group is being moved by the mouse before ```setPos``` is called. But this shouldn't happen since ```move_locations``` is called before the event is propagated to items via ```QGraphicsScene.mousePressEvent(self, event)```.

Comment: In reality, there's no such thing as "clicking while the mouse is moving". Mouse move events are instantaneous events that tell that the mouse cursor has a different position, but there's no difference in handling button press/release when a "movement" has happened in the meantime. The mouse movement is just a human perception: there is no "movement" at all, there only is a position change, and mouse press/release events are handled in the same way as they are with a "static" mouse position. Still, it's possible that an item "assumes" a "movement", but it's not completely reliable.

Comment: As previously said, if child items don't change their geometries (position and bounding rect), overriding `boundingRect()` of the group is unnecessary. So, considering the case at hand, you can fix these issues by removing that. Still, this may be an important bug that needs to be fixed or clarified. My suggestion is to create a MRE (that is *really* minimal, including removal of unnecessarily big scene boundaries and any scene boundary checking at all), and, if possible, verify its results with PyQt and PySide bindings (and for Qt5 too); if they're consistent, report it on bugreports.qt.io.

Comment: Thanks for all of the detailed help and advice. I verified that the problem persists in PySide and PyQt5. I will make a report.

Comment: Post a [mre] with debugging details. Anyway, you are temporarily adding and removing a graphics item inside a mouse event handler. That is not recommended and you are relying on an undocumented feature. If you want to move multiple objects at once, implement a loop for multiple objects.

Comment: @relent95 To be honest, I've just been doing everything in a text editor. At any rate, thanks for the advice. Moving all of the item group creation/destruction out of mouse event handlers seems to have resolved the issue.